# How to resolve error Cannot assign to read only property 'defaults' of object '[object Object]' in react and grapesjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grapesjs

I am integrating drop down web builder with react and grapesjs but getting error while initializing grapesjs

This is my editor component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { API_HOST } from "./api_utils";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import TopNav from "./components/TopNav";
import geditorConfig from "./api_utils/geditor_config";
import PageSection from "./components/PageSection";

const Editor = () => {
  const [editor, setEditor] = useState(null);
  const [assets, setAssets] = useState([]);
  const { pageId } = useParams();

  const { pageStore } = useSelector((state) => state);
  const { pages } = pageStore;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getAllAssets() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${API_HOST}assets/`);
        setAssets(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setAssets(error.message);
      }
    }

    getAllAssets();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const editor = geditorConfig(assets, pageId); // Getting error at this line
    setEditor(editor);
  }, [pageId, assets]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        id="navbar"
        className="sidenav d-flex flex-column overflow-scroll position-fixed"
      >
        <nav className="navbar navbar-light">
          {/* <div className="container-fluid">
            <span className="navbar-brand mb-0 h3 logo">Code Dexterous</span>
          </div> */}
        </nav>
        <PageSection pages={pages} />
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
      <div
        className="main-content position-relative w-85 start-15"
        id="main-content"
      >
        <TopNav />
        <div id="editor"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is my geditorConfig  method

```
const geditorConfig = (assets, pageId) => {
  $(".panel__devices").html("");
  $(".panel__basic-actions").html("");
  $(".panel__editor").html("");
  $("#blocks").html("");
  $("#styles-container").html("");
  $("#layers-container").html("");
  $("#trait-container").html("");

  // Content for Preview
  const navbar = $("#navbar");
  const mainContent = $("#main-content");
  const panelTopBar = $("#main-content > .navbar-light");

  const editor = grapesjs.init({ // GETTING ERROR HERE 
    container: "#editor",
    blockManager: {
      appendTo: "#blocks",
    },
    styleManager: styleManager,
    layerManager: layerManager,
    traitManager: traitManager,
    selectorManager: selectorManager,
    panels: panels,
    deviceManager: deviceManager,
    assetManager: { assets: assets, upload: false },
    storageManager: storageSetting(pageId),
    canvas: {
      styles: styles,
      scripts: scripts,
    },
    plugins: [
      tailwindComponent,
      gjsBlockBasic,
      swiperComponent,
      grapesjsBlockBootstrap,
      grapesjsPluginExport,
      grapesjsStyleBg,
      chartLibComponent,
    ],
    pluginsOpts: {
      tailwindComponent: {},
      gjsBlockBasic: {},
      swiperComponent: {},
      grapesjsBlockBootstrap: {},
      grapesjsPluginExport: {},
      grapesjsStyleBg: {},
      chartLibComponent: {},
    },
  });

  addEditorCommand(editor);
  editor.on("run:preview", () => {
    console.log("It will trigger when we click on preview icon");
    // This will be used to hide border
    editor.stopCommand("sw-visibility");
    // This will hide the sidebar view
    navbar.removeClass("sidebar");
    // This will make the main-content to be full width
    mainContent.removeClass("main-content");

    // This will hide top panel where we have added the button
    panelTopBar.addClass("d-none");
  });
  editor.on("stop:preview", () => {
    // This event is reverse of the above event.
    console.log("It will trigger when we click on cancel preview icon");
    editor.runCommand("sw-visibility");
    navbar.addClass("sidebar");
    mainContent.addClass("main-content");
    panelTopBar.removeClass("d-none");
  });
  editor.on("component:selected", (component) => {
    const newTool = {
      icon: "fa fa-plus-square",
      title: "Check Toolbar",
      commandName: "new-tool-cmd",
      id: "new-tool",
    };

    const defaultToolbar = component.get("toolbar");
    const checkAlreadyExist = defaultToolbar.find(
      (toolbar) => toolbar.command === newTool.commandName
    );
    if (!checkAlreadyExist) {
      defaultToolbar.unshift({
        id: newTool.id,
        attributes: { class: newTool.icon, title: newTool.title },
        command: newTool.commandName,
      });
      component.set("toolbar", defaultToolbar);
    }
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    let categories = editor.BlockManager.getCategories();
    categories.each((category) => category.set("open", false));
  }, 2000);
  return editor;
};
```

[This is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au4uR.png)

I am trying to integrate website builder and using mongodb to store all the created pages that what page id is i am rending stored content for editing previous page and on home page added functionality to add new pages

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
            const types = editor.DomComponents.getTypes();

            types.forEach((cy: any) => {
                editor.DomComponents.addType(cy.id, {
                    model: {
                        defaults: {
                            dropabble: true,
                        }
                    },
                });
            });
```